# add data-attributes to form elements in TYPO3 FORM

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i want to implement parsley in a form made with the FORM extension in TYPO3 9 LTS. I cannot find a possibility to add data attributes to any form element, neither in the fluid templates nor in the yaml files. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it is easy enough ... shame on me :-)

```
 type: Text
   identifier: myname
   properties:
     fluidAdditionalAttributes:
       placeholder: 'Name of Field'
       data-something: 'anything'
```